# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'exec' at file:///android_asset/www/index.html

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

- using PhoenGap 2.2.0
- Executed \bin\create C:\Temp\Test com.test Test
- Had following output

> Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
>       Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

```
Creating new android project...
Building jar and js files...
Copying template files...
Copying js, jar & config.xml files...
Copying cordova command tools...
Updating AndroidManifest.xml and Main Activity...
```

- Imported Project
- - On eclipse (4.2.0) did
- - File > New > Project > Android > Android Project from Existing Code
- - Selected the folder C:\Temp\Test
- - Checked "Copy project into workspace"
- Making changes
- - Checked res\xml\config.xml and the line `<plugin name="Notification" value="org.apache.cordova.Notification"/>` is present
- - Checked that index.html has the cordova-2.2.0.js included
- - Case#1 Opened index.html and modified from

`<script type="text/javascript">
       app.initialize();
</script>`

to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showAlert(msg){
navigator.notification.alert(msg);
}
document.addEventListener("deviceready", showAlert('You are the winner!'), false);
app.initialize();
</script>
```

I get following error
`11-25 10:29:58.399: E/Web Console(14604): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'alert' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:40`

- - Case#2 Opened index.html and modified from

`<script type="text/javascript">
    app.initialize();
</script>`

to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function successAlert(){}
function errorAlert(){}
function showAlert(msg){
cordova.exec(successAlert, errorAlert, "Notification","alert", [msg]);
}
document.addEventListener("deviceready", showAlert('You are the winner!'), false);
app.initialize();
</script>
```

I get following error
`11-25 10:25:06.575: E/Web Console(14149): Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'exec' at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:42`
}

I'm sure that I missed something...just that I'm not able to conclude what is it. Please help me out.

Comment: Just an FYI: I'm facing these problems on live device when deployed using USB. I haven't tried anything else. Android OS : 4.2

Comment: I have the error --Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'exec'-- as well and can't find any solution. I included "cordova-2.2.0.js" into my "index.html" and calling "nfc.addNdefListener(callback, [success], [error]);" implemented in "phonegap-nfc.js". In there is the "cordova.exec();" method called. I'm using cordova 2.2.0 and the phonegap-nfc plugin https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc. But it's nowhere working even if i'm calling the exec method directly in index.html.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will call `showAlert` immediately, instead of delaying to when the event fires:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", showAlert('You are the winner!'), false)
```

Instead do this

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
    showAlert('You are the winner!')
}, false)
```